# TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters NodeJS + Dynamics

Tags: node.js, https, dynamics-crm, node-request

I am making a https.request to Dynamics CRM to fetch data for contacts in node js.

Below is my code:

```
var options = { path: '/api/data/v8.2/contacts?$select=address1_city,address1_line1,address1_line2,address1_line3,contactid,emailaddress1,firstname,fullname,middlename,mobilephone,statecode,suffix,telephone1,vcm_npiid,vcm_prescriberspeciality,vcm_prescriberstatus,vcm_recordtype,vcm_symphonyid&$orderby=fullname asc&$filter=statecode eq 0',
  host: 'xxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com',
  method: 'GET',
  headers:
   { Authorization: 'Bearer xxxxxxx',
     Accept: 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     Prefer: 'odata.includeannotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue',
     'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
     'OData-Version': '4.0' 
   } 
} 

var crmrequest = https.request(options, function(response) { ... }
```

I get this error :

> TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters

when I try without space between asc and also in eq 0 query[ by deleting it ]. It works. 
Any workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [querystring.stringify](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options) or [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) in order to escape special characters.

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const path = '/api/data/v8.2/contacts';
const qs = {
    $select: 'address1_city,address1_line1,address1_line2,address1_line3,contactid,emailaddress1,firstname,fullname,middlename,mobilephone,statecode,suffix,telephone1,vcm_npiid,vcm_prescriberspeciality,vcm_prescriberstatus,vcm_recordtype,vcm_symphonyid',
    $orderby: 'fullname asc',
    $filter: 'statecode eq 0'
}

const options = { 
  path: path + '?' + querystring.stringify(qs),
  host: 'xxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com',
  method: 'GET'
  /* ... */
}
```

---

```
const path = '/api/data/v8.2/contacts';
const query ='$select=address1_city,address1_line1,address1_line2,address1_line3,contactid,emailaddress1,firstname,fullname,middlename,mobilephone,statecode,suffix,telephone1,vcm_npiid,vcm_prescriberspeciality,vcm_prescriberstatus,vcm_recordtype,vcm_symphonyid&$orderby=fullname asc&$filter=statecode eq 0';


const options = { 
  path: path + '?' + encodeURI(query),
  host: 'xxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com',
  method: 'GET'
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: For me the first option worked flawless. Didn't try the other one

Comment: It works, but the first one is the way to go in my opinion. Glad it helped!